# how to get output of a running nohup process if nohup.out gets deleted

Tags: freebsd, nohup

I have a nohup process running on my FreeBSD 8.4 box. Initially I was looking at nohup console messages output through

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

But I accidentally deleted nohup.out file. How can I access the console messages now ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, though the file is still there for as long as a process keeps it open, because it was `unlink`-ed, it is no longer accessible.

If you need to continue seeing the messages as they are generated, you can enable `ktrace` on the process, that generates them:

```
% ktrace -p PID
% kdump -l
```

The above will list *all* system-calls made by the process, however, not just writes to `stdout` and `stderr`, so it may be a bit overwhelming and/or require additional filtering to get only, what you wish to see.

If you want a copy of the file, you can use one of the general-purpose utilities such as `tsk_recover` from the [sysutils/sleuthkit](http://FreshPorts.org/sysutils/sleuthkit) port. The usual wisdom of not writing to the filesystem containing the accidentally-deleted files, that you wish to restore, does not apply, because you still have a process keeping the file open.

However, the recovery will create a *copy* of the deleted file -- anything written to it by the same process later will not be in the copy.

Sorry, I can not think of anything else... On Solaris I was once able to restore a deleted file, that was still-open by a process by going into `/proc/PID/fd/...`, but procfs on FreeBSD does not offer such functionality...

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58949/recovering-deleted-file-held-open-by-apache), the `/proc/PID/fd` method would also work on Linux, but FreeBSD's linprocfs does not offer the feature either. A shame, really...